# mysql / sqlite: return id where a column has more than once a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a subquery (for example **select ID from mytable where cccccc="aaa3"**) which returns the ids 1 and 2. Now I want a further query which given as input these IDs(1 and 2) to return only The ID which has more than one myprop columns with value 0. This ID is ID 2 (there are 3 such columns). How can I achieve this?

```
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
| ID        | myprop       |   bbbb   | cccccc |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     1     |      1       |2000/09/10|  aaa1  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     1     |      0       |2002/09/20|  aaa2  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     1     |      3       |2012/10/01|  aaa3  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     1     |      4       |2012/10/01|  aaa4  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     2     |      1       |2012/10/01|  bbb1  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     2     |      0       |2012/10/01|  bbb2  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     2     |      0       |2012/10/01|  bbb3  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
|     2     |      0       |2012/10/01|  aaa3  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return only the ids, you can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(myprop = 0) >= 2;
```

If you want the details for the `0` and have a unique column of some sort, then I recommend `exists` like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where myprop = 0 and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.myprop = t.myprop and
                    t2.<unique col> <> t.<unique col>
             );
```

And if you want all rows, including the non-0 rows, then slightly different logic is needed:

```
select t.*
from t
where (select count(*)
       from t t2
       where t2.id = t.id and t2.myprop = 0 
      ) >= 2;
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum( myprop = 0 ) over (partition by id) as cnt_0
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_0 >= 2;
```